# Static Site Incorporated in RoR App

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms

Recently just transferred our entire site into a RoR app (by bringing all directories) into the public folder. Reason we did this is we plan on building out our site with new features and want to start storing data in a db from our various forms.

Currently all of those forms are built in HTML...I'm confused on how to rebuild these on the RoR app so its saving to the database.

I've set up a "subscription" controller and model with appropriate attributes but confused where I go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extract the forms to Views, and load them by ajax on your static templates.

Let's assume, you need to make `create form` for Subscription model.
Add to SubscriptionController two actions:

```
class SubscriptionController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  # action to add page form via ajax
  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  # submit form
  def create 
    subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params(params))
    subscription.create!
    render :file => 'public/greetings.html' and return  
  end
```

Note: you need add `resources :subscriptions` to `routes.rb` file.

Create partial file, which will render the form partial via ajax:

```
#app/views/subscriptions/new.js.erb
$(".new-subscription-container").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('subscriptions/form')) %>");
```

Create form partial:

```
#app/views/subscriptions/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @subscription, url: {action: "create"} do |subscription_form| %>
  <%= subscription_form.text_field :user_name %> <!-- field from model -->
  <!-- ... other fields -->
  <%= submit_tag "Create!" %>
<% end %>
```

Update your static template: add div with classname 'new-subscription-container'.

Add ajax call to your public template:

```
<script type="text/javacsript">
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({type:"GET",url:"/subscriptions/new.js"});
  });
</script>
```

Test it. To bun spam, add captcha.
p.s.: Not debugged, just from head.

Comment: not sure exactly where to start with this one...Everything is in the public folder at the moment...Also, set up my User Model and Controller. There are two different forms in two different directories...Starting off with the first one, I'd like to get the form captured by the database. Is it possible to create _form.html.erb in my app/users/views/ and call render from the public folder? Or How can I go about doing this.